# Asking WebView to load webpage from different class

Tags: cocoa, class, webview

I have a WebView that I need to ask to load a website from a different class.Therefore I implemented the following function:

```
-(void)performResearch:(NSString *)aString {  
    NSLog(@"Received Request!");  
    [[researcher mainFrame]
    loadRequest:[NSURLRequest
    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aString]]]; 
}
```

In my other class, I call the function like this:

```
Researcher *res = [[Researcher alloc] init];
[res performResearch:@"http://www.twitter.com"];
[res release];
```

I get no compiler errors and the NSLog does indeed get called, however the WebView doesn't load the webpage. No errors in the Log either.I'm puzzled.

Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show where `researcher` is declared, but it looks like a normal instance variable. Where does the value come from?

If it comes from outside the `Researcher` class, then it looks like it is `nil` because your other class is creating a new `Researcher` instance but not providing the `researcher` attribute.. If you pass messages to `nil` objects, the message is ignored. That is why you don't get an error. Try breaking the load request line out into several lines and log the values of the objects.

EDIT:

Interface Builder sets the `UIWebView` attribute of one particular instance of the `Researcher` class. To update that web view, you need to call `performResearch` on the same instance. You cannot use a new instance because it won't be connected to a web view at all.

If possible, you should pass the original `Researcher` object to the new class and use that instead:

```
[self.researcher performResearch:@"http://www.twitter.com"];
```

Comment: Researcher declared here: "@interface Researcher : NSObject {" in a file named Researcher.h. I want to access it via a different file.

Comment: I mean this researcher in the `performResearcher` method: `[researcher mainFrame]`

Comment: How can I pass the original object to the new class? I have never done that before :/

Comment: You have to find an object or method where the original object is available and you can pass it along down to the place where you create the new class. i.e. Your view controller may contain object A that creates object B that needs to call `performResearch`. You would need to pass the `Researcher` object down from the view controller to object A, which would pass it to object A. Object A could then use it.

If this is impossible, a singleton might help (you can search stack overflow on how to do this).

Comment: I have fixed it by using "sharedInstance". It now works great! :-)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> -(void)performResearch:(NSString *)aString {  
>     NSLog(@"Received Request!");  
>     [[researcher mainFrame]
>     loadRequest:[NSURLRequest
>     requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aString]]]; 
> }
> ```
>
> In my other class, I call the function like this:
>
> ```
> Researcher *res = [[Researcher alloc] init];
> [res performResearch:@"http://www.twitter.com"];
> [res release];
> ```

Within `performResearch:`, the object you sent the `performResearch:` message to in the latter code is `self`. `researcher` is some other variable; you are talking to a different object that is probably not this Researcher.

In [your comment on Colin Gislason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347658/asking-webview-to-load-webpage-from-different-class/2347929#comment-2320418), you say that `researcher` is not a Researcher, but is a WebView. You would do well to correct this inaccurate choice of variable name.

Once you've renamed the variable to something more accurate, like `webView`, you then need to make sure there is something in it. Simply having a variable is of no help; you need to have a pointer to an object in the variable. Otherwise, the pointer in the variable is `nil`, and messages to `nil` do nothing at all. They do not crash, they do not fail, they do not succeed, they do not break—execution continues as if nothing happened, because it did.

You say that the variable is an IBOutlet; this implies that you mean to hook up the outlet in IB. One possible cause of your problem is that you forgot to do that, which would explain the variable containing `nil`. Make sure it's connected in IB.

The other possible cause of your problem is that this nib has not been loaded. If the Researcher object owns the nib, then it is generally its responsibility to load it, which means you need to do that. If some other object is loading a nib with both a Researcher and a WebView in it, then your creation of *another* Researcher object in the latter code snippet is wrong; this second Researcher object has no relation to the one in the nib, nor has it a WebView from any source. In this latter case, you would have to cut out the creation of a Researcher object, and use the one in the nib.

That last solution may require adding an outlet to the object whose class hosts the second code snippet. I disapprove of that solution. It's difficult to say what you should do because I'm not sure where Researcher objects fit in [the MVC triumvirate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html). I suspect you need to think some more about which category it's in; I think that it should be a Controller, and that you will need to do some refactoring to re-establish the boundaries you should have between powers.

Failure to uphold MVC in your app generally results in Cocoa being harder to use than it normally is.

Comment: I think that the problem is that I am not using the same instance...I need to figure out now how to pass the original object to the new class...

Comment: David Schiefer: See my second-to-last paragraph.